# Regarding CFLocaleCopyCurrent API incorrect return value

Tags: macos, cocoa, foundation, core-foundation, macos-high-sierra

At my workplace, we are in a situation where following standalone code below,

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>  
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>  
#include <vector>  
#include <memory>  
#include <boost/cast.hpp>  

   // Reference release  
    struct reference_close  
    {  
        void operator()(const void *ref) const  
        {  
            CFRelease(static_cast<CFTypeRef>(ref));  
        }  
    }; // end of reference_close structure  

    typedef std::unique_ptr<const void, reference_close>  reference_uptr;  

     std::string get_user_locale()  
    {  
        reference_uptr  ref_ptr(CFLocaleCopyCurrent());  
        CFLocaleRef     locale_ref(static_cast<CFLocaleRef>(ref_ptr.get()));  
        if (locale_ref == nullptr)  
        {  
            return std::string();  
        }  
        const size_t       default_size(128);  
        std::vector<char>  buff(default_size);  
        CFStringRef        str_ref(CFLocaleGetIdentifier(locale_ref));  
//        CFStringRef        str_ref((CFStringRef)CFLocaleGetValue(locale_ref,kCFLocaleLanguageCode));  
       if (str_ref != nullptr)  
        {  
            CFIndex  len(CFStringGetLength(str_ref) + 1);  
            if (len > boost::numeric_cast<CFIndex>(default_size))  
            {  
                buff.resize(len);  
            }  

            buff[0] = 0;  
            if (!CFStringGetCString(str_ref, &buff[0], len, kCFStringEncodingISOLatin1))  
            {  
                return std::string();  
            }  
        }  

        return std::string(&buff[0]);  
    } // end of get_user_locale()  

int main()  
{  
    std::cout << "get_user_locale() : "<<get_user_locale() << std::endl;  

    return 0;  
}
```

gives us a different output on OS X 10.12 and 10.13 beta.

This is what we do in a nutshell.

On 10.12 machine

1) Set the preference language as ru  and region as RU

2) Restart the machine

3) Get the output of "defaults read -g AppleLocale" to make sure that output is
{
  ru_RU
}

4) Compile the code, run the exe. We get the output as { ru_RU }.

We then repeat the steps 1) to 3) on OS X 10.13 (beta) machine and then run the same exe (created on 10.12, you might ask why, its because of some our internal build system restrictions ) on 10.13 machine and the output we get is "en_RU" which is not correct.

Are we missing something here ? Or is this a known problem in OS X 10.13 (beta) ? If so, how do we fix this ?

**UPDATE**

We also wrote a following Objective-C code to use NSLocale interface and that too gave us same results i.e ru_RU on 10.12 and en_RU on 10.13 (beta)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>  
int main()  
{  
    @autoreleasepool  
    {   
        NSLog(@"localeIdentifier: %@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]);  
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason we were getting an incorrect value is because our app was not localized into the locale we expected e.g `ru`. 
We corrected this by adding an empty `ru.lproj` directory into our app's `Contents/Resources` directory and the API started giving us the correct answer.